# MySQL Export with replacement on single column

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to export a table (ideally via phpmyadmin), along with replacing the content of the fields for a single column with a #, within MySQL.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a query like that:

```
SELECT
   list,
   of_your_wanted,
   columns,
   '#' as column_to_replace,
FROM
   yourtable;
```

and export the result via phpMyAdmin. If you do this more than once I recommend to create a view for this.

[image: screenhot of phpMyAdmin]